# How to pass parameter to js function from template parameter array

Tags: javascript, html, tornado

I generated in tornado template table with cities and I am trying to have like last column details button

```
{% if globals().has_key('results')  %}
   {% for result in results %}
     <tr>
         <td>{{result['name']}}</td>
         <td>{{result['citizens']}}</td>
         <td style="width:100px; height:100px;">
          <div class="ui-grid-b">
          <a class="ui-block-a ui-icon-detail" onclick="showDetails('{{id}}',{{result['city_id']}});" data-role="ui-li-aside" data-icon="right_arrow" data-theme="a"></a>
          </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
    {% end %}
{% end %}
```

and on click to load on another page with parameters in url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDetails(id, city_id)
       {
          window.location = '/cities?id='+id+'&city_id='+city_id;
        }
</script>
```

How to pass parameters to show details function ? (I cannot use ', I tried with \" but it doesn't work). Results is list of dictionaries with keys name, citizens, city_id.
{{ }} is used by tornado template to access passed parameter.

Comment: why not just use a href, is there a particular reason you are using a js function to make a link link?

Comment: what result are you getting now? what html is generated with current code? is it looks like this `onclick="showDetails('what is here?',what is it looks like in result?);"` or it replaced with values or what?

Comment: @llamerr yyou need more quotes

Comment: @EricG who cares, i don't see required data. do i need to put `lorem ipsum` in there to make obvious what i wanted to mean? ps: there is no quotes in the example, so i haven't added any

Comment: I mean that your code will give an error, you need `'what is it looks like in result?'` i.e. with quotes. Just trying to help.. I didn't mention that in proper English it should be 'What does it looks like' :P i.e. I tried to be relevant, not critical.

Answer (score 0):

```
   showDetails = function (id, city_id)
       {
          window.location = '/cities?id='+id+'&city_id='+city_id;
        }
```

I think is the easy way

Answer (score 0):

The variable inside the braces will be output directly (or, the string representation of it), so it depends what it is set to.

e.g. if you have:

```
id = 'foo'
results = [{ 'city_id': 'bar' }]
```

and you are passing them to the template, then this line:

```
showDetails('{{id}}',{{result['city_id']}});
```

will be output as follows (you can confirm this with view source):

```
showDetails('foo',bar);
```

I'm guessing you're missing the quotes around `{{result['city_id']}}`, unless `result['city_id']` is an integer, in which case it should work. Single or double quotes are both fine in JavaScript.

However, as @Pete already pointed out, "on click to load on another page with parameters in url" is what we have the `href` attribute for. You can save yourself a lot of work and potential brokenness with:

```
<a href="/cities?id={{ id }}&city_id={{ result['city_id'] }}" ....></a>
```

Comment: I have this doubt. The template frameworks , they replace the templates in the whole html document no matter they are in quotes or not ?